# Clustering Coefficient of zero in the Network

Tags: clustering, networks, igraph

The clustering co-efficient of my real network is zero. As a matter of fact, all the nodes of the network have a clustering coefficient of zero.

I am trying to compare my network to an ensemble of random networks I created using the Erdos-Renyi algorithm with the same number of nodes and edges as my real network. It says online that the clustering coefficient of a real network is much higher than a random network.

In my case, since the clustering coefficient of my network is zero, the situation is the opposite. What can I say about this phenomenon in my report. Any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: Integer division error? 1/2=0

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I don't think so. The network has a total of 361 nodes and 695 edges. Cytoscape gives the value as zero and I think its highly unlikely that the software makes that kind of an error

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I could send you the adjacency matrix file of my network

Comment: Then you probably have a multimodal graph, if you don't get any triangles. Either way, a comparison with ER graphs then is misleading.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Could you please suggest a valid comparison.Please also go through the other question on the topic that I had asked earlier.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse It is actually a cluster of a network split into eight using the GLay algorithm because it gave a high modularity score.  just checked the clustering coefficient of the original full network and that is also zero. The other question that I asked https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279720/how-to-generate-random-networks-for-comparison-with-my-network

Comment: Well, you need to first understand your network. If it is bimodal, you need to understand this. Then you can try to generate a random bimodal network for comparison. Obviously, the CC is useless on bimodal networks unless you project it onto its modes.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I checked and my network is not bimodal. Any other idea is appreciated.

Comment: Further study your data, why you don't have triangles. Maybe trimodal?